# get each first-child text and set to the each parent id

Tags: jquery

I have a table

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>101</td>
        <td>37,17 m<sup>2</sup></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>102</td>
        <td>30,53 m<sup>2</sup></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>103</td>
        <td>10,53 m<sup>2</sup></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and i would like to get text from first  and set it to id of parent  to end like this

```
<tbody>
    <tr id="101">
        <td>101</td>
        <td>37,17 m<sup>2</sup></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="102">
        <td>102</td>
        <td>30,53 m<sup>2</sup></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="103">
        <td>103</td>
        <td>10,53 m<sup>2</sup></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

i wrote something like this

```
var td = $('tobody td:first-child').text(); - returns 101102103

$('tobody tr').attr('id', td); - returns 101102103 for each tr
```

how to separate this ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just iterate over all first `<td>` elements, find the respective parent elements and set their `id` attribute:

```
$('td:first-child').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().attr('id', $(this).text());
});
```

If you have more tables or a bigger document, it makes sense to anchor the operation:

```
$('#table-id').find('td:first-child').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.parent().attr('id', $this.text());
});
```

Comment: i choose your answer because a have more of those tables, thx you guys for help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each` to iterate through `td` and assign the `id` to the parent `tr`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nt3Y8/)**

```
$('td:first-child').each(function(){    
   $(this).closest('tr').attr('id', $.trim($(this).text()));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('tobody tr').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('id', $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text().trim());
});
```

Or simply:

```
$('tbody tr').attr('id' , function(){
  return $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text().trim();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      theId = $this.find('td').first().text();  
  $this.attr('id', theId);
});
```

Please note that numeric ids are only valid in HTML5

Answer (score 0):

Traverse with `.each()` in the `<tr>`:

```
$('tbody tr').each(function(){
   var txt = $.trim($('td:first',this).text());
   $(this).attr('id', txt);
});
```

#### [CHECKOUT THE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ySpBc/)